# easy ui height to take full browser

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-easyui

[Dynamically add tabs](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/layout/tabs2.php)  ...i am trying to create a layout with this example ... and the problem in that the page does not take full height and width of the available space... i tried changing the width and height to 100% of di easyui-tabs tabs-container but this does not work....

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
 <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="addTab('google','http://www.google.com')">google</a>
 <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="addTab('jquery','http://jquery.com/')">jquery</a>
 <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="addTab('easyui','http://jeasyui.com/')">easyui</a>
</div>
<div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="width:400px;height:250px;">
    <div title="Home"></div>
</div>
function addTab(title, url) {
    if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)) {
        $('#tt').tabs('select', title);
    } else {
        var content = '<iframe scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" src="' + url + '"                style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>';
        $('#tt').tabs('add', {
            title: title,
            content: content,
            closable: true
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok..i have got what i was looking for ..they have implemented the same in documentation page.

http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/...i used the same code and works fine.

If you are looking to close the tree,you can use

< li state="closed" >

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="width:400px;height:250px;">
    <div title="Home"></div>
</div>
```

into

```
<div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs">                    
    <div title="Home"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it does as soon as a button is clicked